# Google Apps Script onclick event doesn't work in firefox 20 on mac. Cannot use the given object as a weak map key

Tags: onclick, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, onclicklistener

My Google Apps Script web app stopped working.

Whenever I click on any element that has onclick property I am getting the following error message:
**[11:27:44.243] cannot use the given object as a weak map key**

Is there any workaround? 
How can I get user's response without onclick event?

**My code:**
Note that I am trying to add onclick event using both ways, programmatically in JavaScript and by using HTML.

var by = document.getElementById("yes");
 by.addEventListener('click', submitResponse,false);

This problem was submitted as google apps script issues:
http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2625

thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an acknowledged issue with Apps Script, there isn't much that can be provided here in Stack Overflow.

Here is a bit more context, this was [broken](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/detail?id=1688) and now fixed in Caja. This fix should be reflected in Apps Script in a few days.